# memcpy and then printf, calling stat(), writing in buffer;

Tags: c, printf, system-calls, memcpy

here are includes and my function:

I'm trying to copy `stbuf->st_mode` in buffer with `memcpy` and when reading it back, value is not what I was trying to copy.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <string.h>

void r1_getattr(char* pth, int cfd){
    struct stat* stbuf = malloc(sizeof(stat));

    int res = stat(pth, stbuf);

    printf("(%3o)\n", (stbuf->st_mode)&0777);
    char* wbuf = malloc(256);

    memcpy(wbuf, &(stbuf->st_mode), sizeof(mode_t));
    printf("(%3o)\n", (*(mode_t*)((char*)wbuf))&0777);
}
```

outputs: "(775)" and "( 21)" shouldn't they be the same?

Comment: The recommended idiom `T *p = malloc( sizeof *p );` would have avoided this error

Comment: `memcpy(wbuf, &(stbuf->st_mode), sizeof(mode_t)); printf("(%3o)\n", (*(mode_t*)((char*)wbuf))&0777);` what is this?!

Comment: That's not how you use `mode_t` - first of all, you don't even need to *copy* it anywhere, just use `stbuf->st_mode` as it were. Second: use the macros [from `<sys/stat.h>`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/sysstat.h.html) to determine what the mode means

Comment: If you can _binary and_ `st_mode`, it's an integer, so you don't need to use `memcpy()` to copy its value. And allocating 256 bytes for `wbuf` is overkill, since it's an integer of type `mode_t` as you noted, so use `malloc(sizeof(mode_t))` would have been better. In this end, the code could be `mode_t *wbuf = malloc(sizeof(mode_t)); *wbuf = stbuf->st_mode;`

Comment: Also note your `r1_getattr()` function leaks memory, remember to `free()` the buffers at some point

Comment: And there's no need to `malloc()` a buffer for `struct stat`, in *most* cases, it fit on stack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple typing error:

Replace

```
struct stat *stbuf = malloc(sizeof(stat));
```

with

```
struct stat *stbuf = malloc(sizeof(struct stat));
```

Always funny to see the weird results we get when we use un-initialized memory :-)